# Is there a better way to handle this? (Psql, using TOAD)

Tags: sql, psql, toad

This is a code that was passed to me by selecting users from the database and deleting any that don't exist anymore. Now it works but I think there might be a better way of handling this.

I'm just getting opinions if there are other ways to process this request. Thanks for any input.

```
    SELECT uvt.user_id, 
           ulp.user_id,
           uj.user_id,
           uw.user_id,
           pu.user_id
    FROM U_V_T uvt, 
         U_L_P ulp, 
         U_J uj,
         U_W uw,
         P_U pu 
    WHERE uvt.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM users)
    AND ulp.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM users)
    AND uj.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM users)
    AND uw.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM users)
    AND pu.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM users)
    GROUP BY uvt.user_id,ulp.user_id, uj.user_id, uw.user_id, pu.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a silly way to approach this.  Why would you want every combination of such users?

I would be inclined to put each value on a separate *row* and use `union all`:

```
select 'uvt' as which, user_id
from u_v_t
where user_id not in (select user_id from users)
union all
select 'ulp' as which, user_id
from u_l_p
where user_id not in (select user_id from users)
union all
select 'uj', user_id
from u_j
where user_id not in (select user_id from users)
union all
select 'uw', user_id
from u_w
where user_id not in (select user_id from users)
union all
select 'pu', user_id
from p_u
where user_id not in (select user_id from users);
```

This should be much faster and have essentially the same information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try this out. And yea I have to agree the way the users are handled are a bit out of hand. But you get what you inherit lol.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 'uvt' AS which, user_id
FROM u_v_t
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users)
UNION all
SELECT 'ulp' as which, user_id
FROM u_l_p
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users)
UNION all
SELECT 'uj', user_id
FROM u_j
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'uw', user_id
FROM u_w
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pu', user_id
FROM p_u
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users);
```